# GeoServer Import of MBTiles file Results in Garbled Map

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I created a `mbtiles` file using MapTiler 9.1, and imported it to GeoServer (no errors). When I previewed the layer, it came out all garbled up (see screenshot below). I could see this being an issue with the data import settings, but have no idea where to begin to address this. I don't think the images themselves are corrupted, as they preview fine in MapTiler.

[image]

Oddly enough some tiles seem to render fine at different zoom levels, some garbled, and others not at all.

**Update:** after playing around with Layer Publishing settings, it appears to do with the Interpolation Method. Unfortunately any setting I chose resulted in better or worse images, leading me to believe that the export from MapTiler used some awkward interpolation settings. I am re-exporting now using Nearest Neighbor settings, which is also present in GeoServer.

**Update 2:** the new export didn't change anything, the behavior remained the same in GeoServer. I have the default `raster` style applied to this layer. Seems this might be an issue/incompatibility with the rendering engine?

Comment: For creating mbtiles I usually use plugin Qtiles that works in Qgis 2.18

Comment: I need to use MapTiler because of the manual reference points that align historical maps with current infrastructure.

Comment: At least I think I "need" it, because so far it has been the only software for Mac I have been able to find that allows visual alignment of images of maps over maps (Google, OpenLayers, etc).

Comment: In Qgis you can use its georeferencing tool as well and then Qtiles plugin can be applied

Comment: @Vadym after checking out QGIS with the Georeferencer plugin, it seems you can do overlay georeferencing like in MapTiler. Using the overlay method is so much faster when you have to add hundreds of reference points. Do you have any suggestions for doing something like that in QGIS? I can see that it is a much more powerful program than MapTiler, though.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly to me what do you mean under term 'overlay georeferencing'? I found some youtube video where the technique of georeferencing is explained. Maybe it's what you expect? https://youtu.be/JaZ2bt2AxUg

Comment: This process is basically georeferencing using the raster overlayed over a map layer with some amount of transparency applied. Then you proceed to identify diverging points, click on the raster, which then is hidden, and you proceed to click on the matching point on the map layer. After that the raster is adjusted and you move on to the next diverging point. I made a short clip of one such point. (And as you can see MapTiler is horribly slow at this.) http://share.genealabs.com/yH6gaCe

Comment: Regarding the YouTube link: yes, I have watched that, and it is not quite what I am hoping for, but its close. The back and forth in identifying coordinates to add to the Georeferencer is just too tedious to do when you have 100s or even 1000s of points that need to be georeferenced. That's what the overlay method is so quick (if the software can keep up) . :)

Comment: Now I've got your point. This is the exact technique that I once implemented in commercial Smallworld GIS application. The proposed raster dropped in accordance to scale and resolution onto the center of the view. The only user's task was to shift and rotate the raster. It took me, however, some time to develop such a tool because of the necessity to process different mouse events. Try plugin 'Freehand raster georeferencing' that I found for Qgis 3.2. I have not had to figure out how it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87528/discussion-between-mike-bronner-and-vadym).